# How to include local JS and CSS files in ExtJS APP?

Tags: webpack, extjs

I have several JS and CSS Files that are build externally with webpack.

Currently I include the files withing the index.html file with:

```
    <script src="/build/js/shared.js"></script>
    <script src="/build/js/common.js"></script>
```

but I want to build this app for a mobile device with cordova and these files are not copied withing the build.

I assume I'll have to add them somehow to the app.json file as JS/CSS resources, how can I do that the best way?

**shared.js**

```
import 'underscore';
import 'jquery';
```

**common.js**

```
global.$ = require('jquery');
global.jQuery = require('jquery');

require('bootstrap');
require('sprintf-js');
global._ = require('underscore');
global.moment = require('moment');
global.deepmerge = require('deepmerge');
global.countryList = require('country-list-js');
global.Dropzone = require('dropzone');
require('jquery-file-download');
require('jsrender');

global.md5 = require('crypto-js/md5');

const { format, render, cancel, register } = require('timeago.js');
global.TimeAgo = format;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add files to [js](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/microloader.html#microloader_-_js) property in your `app.json`

Answer (score 1):

to include external css and js files you can register them in 'app.json'. Read the comments in app.json and a look at the [documentation](https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.0.0/guides/resource_management.html). Dont't forget to rebuild/refresh.. the extjs project.

Answer (score 0):

I will just post a `code` based answer for others. 
In app.json add the following:

```
    "js": [
        {
            "path": "${workspace.dir}/vendor/build/runtime.js",
            "bundle": false
        },
        {
            "path": "${workspace.dir}/vendor/build/js/shared.js",
            "bundle": false
        },
        {
            "path": "${workspace.dir}/vendor/build/js/common.js",
            "bundle": false
        }
   "css": [
        {
            "path": "${workspace.dir}/vendor/build/style.css",
            "bundle": false
        }
    ]
```